# Netty: ClosedChannelException when closing channel

Tags: java, netty, channel

Why when i'm trying to close channel, I got ChannelClosedException thrown?
Closing with Channel.close(), exception's stacktrace:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(NioWorker.java:645)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:601)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:119)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:76)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:720)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:200)
    at ru.greencubes.player.PlayerWorkerThread.closeConnection(PlayerWorkerThread.java:107)
    at ru.greencubes.player.PlayerWorkerThread.shutDown(PlayerWorkerThread.java:282)
    at ru.greencubes.player.NetworkPlayerThread.disconnect(NetworkPlayerThread.java:1289)
    at ru.greencubes.player.NetworkPlayerThread.disconnect(NetworkPlayerThread.java:1272)
    at ru.greencubes.server.Server.run(Server.java:1590)
    at ru.greencubes.server.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:12)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should just ignore this. It just told you that the channel was already closed when it tried to write the remaining bytes to the channel. So nothing to worry about.

Comment: I got the same issue. Is there any way to ensure that the remaining bytes are written to the channel before closing it? I have something like `ch.write(msg); ch.close();`

Comment: Yes... Use a ChannelFuture.

ch.write(msg).addListener(ChannelFuture.CLOSE);

Comment: CLOSE doesn't exist in ChannelFuture.

Comment: Sorry its ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE

Comment: It seems that my problem is another one, which we are discussing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975009