# Netty: Closing WebSockets correctly

Tags: websocket, netty

How can I close a WebSocket channel/connection from server side correctly? If I use a `ctx.getChannel().close()`, the `onerror` in the Brwoser (Firefox 9) is thrown:

*The connection to ws://localhost:8080/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading*

I also tried to send a `CloseWebSocketFrame` within the `channelClosed`-method in the `WebSocketServerHandler`:

```
public void channelClosed(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e)
        throws Exception {
    CloseWebSocketFrame close = new CloseWebSocketFrame();
    ctx.getChannel().write(close);
}
```

This throws an `ClosedChannelException` (maybe related [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872106/)?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
ch.write(new CloseWebSocketFrame());
```

then the server will close the connection.  If the connection is not closed soon enough, you can call `ch.close()`.

Comment: After the WebSocket connection is established, my pipe looks like this:`[wsdecoder, wsencoder, webSocketHandler, myDecoder, myEncoder, app]`. So the WebSocketHandler forwards the data to the decoder until it reaches the app. The problem is, that the `app` doesn't know anything about how it's used. So it doesn't know that there is a WebSocketHandler in the pipe at all. Like this, the `app` can be used in other pipes with non-WebSocket-connections as well. Even if I write the `CloseWebSocketFrame` in the app to the `channel`, it will be encoded until it reaches the `WebSocketServerHandler`

Comment: I just tested something: Is it right, that a `ch.write(...)` at any layer of the pipe goes through the whole pipe (from the last to the first handler)? I expected that it's just going back from the layer where we do the `ch.write(...)`

Comment: Because of the last behaviour I introduced a `ChannelClosing` class. I am writing an instance of this on the channel: `ch.write(new ChannelClosing());`. If I find this in my decoder (which converts my application data to WebSockets), I am switching to the `CloseWebSocketFrame`. It works.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
ctx.getChannel().write(new CloseWebSocketFrame()).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

That should send the CloseWebSocketFrame and then close the channel after that.

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using ?

Have you tried todo this:

```
ctx.getChannel().write(ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

?

Comment: Nope. Still the `ClosedChannelException`. The constructor of the `CloseWebSocketFrame` contains `ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER`. I guess I need to use the `CloseWebSocketFrame`.

Comment: The RFC 6455 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-7.4.1) defines: *1001 indicates that an endpoint is "going away", such as a server going down or a browser having navigated away from a page.* This is what I want to use.

Comment: Version: I am using my branch (https://github.com/boldt/netty). Since Netty is modularized, I can't compile it any more.

Comment: For other coming here over google like me: I was playing arround with http channels, for me that was the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem（close a WebSocket channel/connection from server side ）, which was solved in this way：

```
ctx.getChannel().writeAndFlush(new CloseWebSocketFrame(1000, "Server closed connection."));
```